# IE 7/8: Active Pseudo on Block Elements

Tags: css, internet-explorer, pseudo-class

i have run into  problem regarding IE7/8 ignoring the :active pseudo class on  elements with display:block;

**HTML:**

```
<a>My Link</a>
```

**CSS That Works:**

```
a:active{color:yellow}
```

**CSS That Fails:**

```
a{display:block}
a:active{color:yellow}
```

Does anyone know of a solution to this, or will I have to resort to JS?

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xbLDM/

Answer (score 3):

Ironically, @Kevin already "fixed" your problem without even realising.

Change the HTML from this:

```
<a>My Link</a>
```

to this:

```
<a href="#">My Link</a>
```

and it works in IE7, see: http://jsbin.com/exuga3

Unexpected things like this can happen when you have `<a>` tags without an `href` attribute.

If you *really* don't want the "hand mouse pointer", specify `cursor: default`: http://jsbin.com/exuga3/4

Comment: Thanks for your help. This does seem to work in IE7 and the href attribute doesn't seem to make a difference. The problem I am having in my local test environment is still happening. I will post another example.

Comment: I think the source of my problem was to do with having child elements inside the a tag. From my tests this seems to render :active useless in IE<9

Comment: A quick test seems to confirm: http://jsbin.com/exuga3/6 - the "ink" bit is a child element of the `a`, and it doesn't trigger `:active` in IE8.