# Pseudo classed not working

Tags: html, css

I want to change a link color on active. So I use :active CSS method but it is not working fine in ie8 and ie9. working fine in rest of the browser.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style>
a { display:inline-block; font-size:14px; color:#FFFFFF; border-radius:10px; background:#F00}

a span { display:block; padding:15px;}

a:active { background:#00F}

</style>

</head>

<body>
<a href="#"><span>mylink</span></a>

</body>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594102/active-css-selector-not-working-for-ie8-and-ie9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to...

```
a:active, a:focus { background:#00F}
```

---

http://jsfiddle.net/dRE7c/1/

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with `:active` and IE 8/9, and also with `:active` and `display:block`.
Take a look at these:

- [:active css selector not working for IE8 and IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594102/active-css-selector-not-working-for-ie8-and-ie9)
- [IE 7/8: Active Pseudo on Block Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390712/ie-7-8-active-pseudo-on-block-elements)